# Wipe clean logfile on daily basis with logrotate

Tags: linux, logrotate

I want to clean a Docker container logs every day (no need to store/archive the data). I created a file called `docker` in `/etc/logrotate.d` and put the following inside:

```
/var/lib/docker/containers/*/*.log {
  rotate 0      #do not keep archives
  daily         
  missingok
  copytruncate  #continue working in the same log file
}
```

well, but it doesn't work. So, obviously something in my logrotate configuration isn't right. AFAIK, I don't need to setup crontab for this. Is my configuration wrong? Is there anything that I am missing?

Is there a way to run and test `logrotate` without having to wait a day?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rotate 0` is redundant here, `0` is the default for rotation, which means, no rotation and old ones are removed.

You can test it using,

```
$ logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.d/docker
```

It might be better to test it by putting `rotate 1` and then with `rotate 0` to check if `logrotate` is functioning correctly.

If `logrotate` is installed correctly, then one would have a `crontab` entry in `/etc/cron.daily/logrotate`. This file reads the configuration file `/etc/logrotate.conf` which includes anything under `/etc/logrotate.d`

HTH